# Multiple StatefulService Replica Listeners of type FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener with named listeners

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

Basically I want to be able to read from the secondary replicas. So I tried to add another named listener with the listenerOnSecondary parameter on the read-only listener. But SF cannot create instance of this stateful service when deployed locally.

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    yield return
        new ServiceReplicaListener(context => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this),
            "StatefulReadWriteCommunicationListener");
    yield return
        new ServiceReplicaListener(context => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this),
            "StatefulReadOnlyCommunicationListener", listenOnSecondary: true);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify -why- you are trying to read from the secondaries? What problem are you trying to solve? Generally you really don't want to read from secondary replicas. Reading from secondary replicas is discouraged since not only can you see stale data (consistent data from the past), you can see changes that are not yet quorum committed and hence could be undone (false progress). If you are going to be reading from secondaries you must be very careful with what you are reading and what you are doing with the information.

Comment: I thought I read from the documentation that primary replica are for read and writes and secondaries are read-only. And since I use the reliable dictionary to store lookup/hot data, it will be efficient if I do the read in the secondary replicas. So when should I use `listenOnSecondary: true` ?

Comment: It will be efficient, but it probably isn't _correct_ . You should almost never read from secondaries today unless you don't care about the consistency of the information you are reading. While you _can_ read from secondaries it does not mean you _should_. You need to describe _why_ you want to today. For example, if you are just trying to solve a performance problem, probably partitioning the service so some of the reads/writes would go to other nodes in the first place is the better way to solve the problem. Don't prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Use only the second listener.
Specify the target replica to communicate with, when creating the ServiceProxy. This is a parameter in the Create method.

In that example you mentioned, they use two specific endpoints, one enabled for communication with secondary replicas, and one not enabled.

Comment: the problem right now is it's not creating an instance of this service bec it seems to complain about this two listeners (i think bec if I remove one it works).

Comment: Yes, remove the first one.

Comment: So you mean I don't have to create two listeners. But when I create the proxy, I will specify in the Create method?